# активное меню после перехода на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

Добрый день. возник такой вопрос. Нужно оставить активными меню, при переходе на новую страницу или просто обновления страницы, которые были открыты.

У меня получилось сделать только для одного меню, которое было выбрано. При переходе на другую страницу я добавляю к URL'у hash (например #Submenu1), затем скриптом считываю его и открываю это подменю при загрузке страницы.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var x = window.location.hash;
    var hash = x.hash;
    $(hash).attr("class", "mainmenu collapse in")
});
```

Я пробую искать меню которые активны, но проблема в том, что сначала выполняется .click, а только потом открывается само меню. В итоге ищется на одно меню меньше.

```
$('a.bm').click(function () {
    $n = $('div.mainmenu.collapse.in');
});
```

Вторая проблема заключается в том, что  `$('div.mainmenu.collapse.in');` выдаёт результат типа: `[div#SubMenu11.mainmenu.collapse.in, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "div.mainmenu.collapse.in"]`
а мне хотелось бы получать только id этого элемента, а не всю строку .

Меню.

```
int index = 1;
    var ID = "SubMenu" + index;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (groupName != reader["GROUPNAME"].ToString())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
            {
            @: </div>
            }
            groupName = reader["GROUPNAME"].ToString();
            ID = "SubMenu"+index;
            @: <a href="#@ID" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success bm" data-toggle="collapse">@groupName &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a><div class="mainmenu collapse" id="@ID">
        }
        var link = string.Format("/{0}{1}", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, reader["URL"]);
        @: <a href="@link#@ID" class="list-group-item list-group-subitem " data-parent="@ID" description="@reader["DESCRIPTION"].ToString()">@reader["DOCNAME"].ToString()</a>
        index++;
```

так выглядит скомпилированный html код в браузере

```
<a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success bm" data-toggle="collapse">Registration &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a><div class="mainmenu collapse" id="SubMenu1">
         <a href="/en/Template/Document/0948EA93957144459ED50CC98B5B1CA3#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item list-group-subitem " data-parent="SubMenu1" description="">Disclosure All docs</a>
         <a href="/en/Template/Document/63EA8AEB085F4ABCA34A02046B5188DC#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item list-group-subitem " data-parent="SubMenu1" description="Disclosure Part 2">Disclosure New</a>
         <a href="/en/Template/Document/80EBAB437EED4301809B252CC2A4B73C#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item list-group-subitem " data-parent="SubMenu1" description="">Disclosure  Submitted</a>
         <a href="/en/Template/Document/4BC79C93960E4ADEA04618337241EFCF#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item list-group-subitem " data-parent="SubMenu1" description="">Disclosure assigned</a>
         <a href="/en/Template/Document/BE1F59796784486D9131E65E888539A3#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item list-group-subitem " data-parent="SubMenu1" description="Inventor Application">Inventor Application</a>
         <a href="/en/Template/Document/735DC6864BFD44DC9FC771FBFB462E8D#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item list-group-subitem " data-parent="SubMenu1" description="Assessments">Assessments</a>
             </div>
```

Comment: "В итоге ищется на одно меню меньше." - что тут имеется ввиду?

Comment: "а мне хотелось бы получать только id этого элемента" - используйте функцию id().

Comment: При открытии меню у меня не находит его. при закрытии его у меня находит это как бы "активное" меню , хотя я его закрываю. в итоге у меня получается так что поиск идет впереди клика.

Comment: А приведите html-код самого меню.

Comment: Я имел ввиду, отредактируйте код вашего вопроса )

Comment: Ага, вижу. А активный пункт меню каким-то классом отмечается? Типа active там или что-то вроде.

Comment: тут bootstrap и при активном меню в класс '<div class="mainmenu collapse" id="SubMenu1">'  добавляется класс in . получается вот так '<div class="mainmenu collapse in" id="SubMenu1">'

Comment: А почему тогда пытаетесь делать пункты активными через имитацию клика по ним, а не через просто добавление этого класса к нужному пункту меню?

Comment: я уже разобрался во всем почти. только остался последний вопрос. как мне просмотреть все дерево меню и выбрать id тех элементов у которых class="collapse in"  ?

Comment: используйте код типа такого `$('#menu').find('collapse in').each(function(){alert($(this).id())});`

Comment: да, все получилось , большое спасибо !

Comment: Здорово. Я тогда вынесу свои комментарии в отдельный ответ на ваш вопрос, вы сможете оценить его и отметить как верный ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сделать пункт меню активным скорее всего можно просто добавив к нему класс `in`.
2. Выбрать все пункты меню с классом `in` можно примерно таким кодом: `$('#menu').find('collapse in').each(function(){alert($(this).id())});`.